# How long does "half an hour" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-usage, phrase-meaning, ambiguity

Consider the declaration A:

> 1. I'll be gone for thirty minutes.

as compared to

> 2. I'll be gone for half an hour.

Similarly, consider declaration B:

> 1. I'll be back within 30 minutes.

versus

> 2. I'll be back within half of an hour.

Two questions: How does the contextual impact alter the syntax, if at all,  between A and B (".. gone for" vs. ".. back within"), particularly as pertaining to choice of nearby words; and What is the semantic difference, if any, between sets 1 and 2 ("half an hour" vs. "thirty minutes")?

If there is a difference, then how is it quantified? Is "half an hour" equivalent to 30 minutes, or does it connote a range—and if the latter, then what range? Does the range vary depending on context? Could it be as high as plus-minus 5 minutes (i.e., between 25 to 35 minutes), plus-minus 10 minutes (i.e., between 20 to 40 minutes), or something else?, and dependent on what?

Answer (score 3):

It depends greatly on the context.

A half-hour TV drama or quiz show will be timed very accurately to 30 minutes as it has to fit the schedule.

A recipe which calls for a dish to be cooked for 30 minutes at 200°C will indicate that the cook should examine it after about 27 minutes, see if it's done and, perhaps, cook it for another 5 minutes.

A half-hour journey, however, could take an hour or more if the traffic is heavy or there has been a road accident.

If someone says "I'm closing the shop for half an hour because I'm going to lunch" they could be back at anytime from 25 to 40 minutes after they leave.

"30 minutes" is usually more precise than "half an hour" and "37 minutes" is usually even more precise but, as I said, it does depend on the context.

Comment: Your first and last remarks are two cases that particularly occurred (but which I omitted from the description for brevity)—Thanks for mentioning them and the other three! Of course with-out commercials an hour-slot tv program's actual aired content duration is shorter (Apparently now again the topic is  closed so that it can be "[updated ..] so it can be answered with facts and citations.". Such an arbitrary application of the rule, not an accurate application of it, And indeed, "100 minutes" is usually implied less precise than "90" which is less precise than "195".  ;"few dozen" even vaguer

Comment: It is interesting that you say that 'half an hour' in the lunch example amounts to 25 to 40 minutes. Why do you think that the interval is not symmetrical?

Comment: @jsw29 Because it takes time to acquire and eat food. The person may underestimate the time slightly but if they are delayed or distracted than the time will be extended by more than the underestimate. Also most people look forward to their lunch break and don't really want to give any of it up. Delays and distractions are more common.

Comment: @11qq00 I'm British, the BBC doesn't have ad breaks even though the commercial channels do.